# Searching for XML tag by value between them and inserting a new tag in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xsd, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

Say I have this test.xml file which has these contents

```
<d>
  <p>
    <n>hi</n>
    <r>
      <s>1.0</s>
    </r>
  </p>

  <p>
    <n>hello</n>
    <r>
      <s>1.0</s>
    </r>
  </p>
</d>
```

I want to add a new <s>2.0</s> for "hello" object as shown below.

```
<d>
  <p>
    <n>hi</n>
    <r>
      <s>1.0</s>
    </r>
  </p>

  <p>
    <n>hello</n>
    <r>
      <s>1.0</s>
      <s>2.0</s>
    </r>
  </p>
</d>
```

I have to do this using shell script. There is a way of searching through the XML DOM and adding tags using xmlstarlet given here http://www.technomancy.org/xml/add-a-subnode-command-line-xmlstarlet/ . But this only describes adding new tag to certain nodes based on attribute value. I do not have any attributes. How can I do it ? Is there any way of doing it using grep ?

Comment: notice how few followers are shown when you hover your mouse over your  xml-parsing tag? Add a tag for xml and/or xmlstarlet to get people that follow those tags to look at your question. Good luck

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet ed -a '//p[n="hello"]/r/s' -t elem -n s -v 2.0 input.xml
```

#### Explanation:

- `ed` ==> edit
- `-a` ==> append
- `-t` ==> type
- `-n` ==> name
- `-v` ==> value