# Changing the value of an XML element depending on the value of another element in the tree

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a *very* large (100+ megabyte uncompressed) XML file storing datasets, and I'm trying to selectively change some values.

For example, say `sample.xml` looks like this:

```
<objects>
  <object>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <constant1>10</constant1>
    <constant2>20</constant2>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>Bar</name>
    <constant1>15</constant1>
    <constant2>40</constant2>
  </object>
<objects>
```

Now I want to change the value of `<constant1>` to 18, but **only** for the object whose `Name` element has value `Foo`.
I've been poking at the XML Starlet documentation but its [article on editing](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html) only has examples on how to look for attributes of elements directly up in the tree, unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

... Apparently I'm an idiot; As demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726143/searching-for-xml-tag-by-value-between-them-and-inserting-a-new-tag-in-shell-scr) you can search for element values the same way you can search for attribute values, so the correct command would be:

`xmlstarlet ed -u '//object[name="Foo"]/const1' -v 18 sample.xml`

... Also, caveat when working on really big files: Without output redirection, `xmlstarlet` prints to stdout. All 100+ megabytes of xml. Oops.